# Python send control + Q then control + A (special keys)

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to send some special keystrokes and am unsure of how to do it.

I need to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to a terminal (I'm using Paramiko).

i have tried

```
shell = client.invoke_shell()

shell.send(chr(10))
time.sleep(5)
shell.send(chr(13))

shell.send('\x11')
shell.send('\x01')

print 'i tried'
```

I can see the two returns go in successfully, but then nothing, it doesnt quit the picocom
(also to note i have it the wrong way round, its expecting ctrl+a, then ctrl+q)

if it helps this is the device
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/interfaces/eesm/software/configuration/guide/4451_config.html#pgfId-1069760

as you can see at step 2

```
Step 2 Exit the session from the switch, press Ctrl-a and Ctrl-q from your keyboard:

Switch# <type ^a^q>
Thanks for using picocom
Router#
```

UPDATE:

i have tried \x01\x16\x11\n but this returns

```
Switch#
Switch#
*** baud: 9600
*** flow: none
*** parity: none
*** databits: 8
*** dtr: down

Switch#
```

this looks like it could be another special command?

Comment: Those kind of signals are rather received by applications (than sent). For what reason do you need them? Probably there is another way to work around.

Comment: im creating a script to build a cisco config, and the router has an internal module that uses picocom, ones ive set up the config via picocom, the keys ctrl + a, then q exits picocom so i can run the rest of my script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works perfectly for me, returning exactly what I would expect.  There are obviously some pieces missing from your code above, so this required a little winging.

```
import sys
import time
import getpass
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1',
            username='apsuser',
            password=getpass.getpass('Password: '))
shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
shell.settimeout(0.25)

shell.send('picocom /dev/ttyS0\n')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(shell.recv(10000))
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()

shell.send('\x01')
shell.send('\x11')

time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(shell.recv(10000))
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
print()
time.sleep(2)
```

And the results are:

```
Password: 

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Apr 14 19:55:57 2016 from 127.0.0.1
picocom /dev/ttyS0
apsuser@Steve-Laptop:~$ picocom /dev/ttyS0
picocom v1.7

port is        : /dev/ttyS0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 9600
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,

Terminal ready

Thanks for using picocom
apsuser@Steve-Laptop:~$
```

So what did I do that your code does not do?

Comment: this has worked, i think the problem was i was sending /n at the end, (sending the enter key with it!) whoops!

Answer (score 6):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + key is actually a "user-friendly" way to enter ASCII control characters. This is done by subtracting 64 from the ASCII code of the entered key (taking the capital letter where applicable). The combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, for example, is equivalent to entering a backspace (H has code 72, `72-64=8`, the backspace character). [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) lists the ASCII control characters associated with their key combinations, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is equivalent to sending the string `"\x01\x11"` through the paramiko Channel:

```
channel = client.invoke_shell()
channel.send('\x01\x11')
```

### Update

To check what is actually transmitted when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> I have devised a small test program:

```
# decode.py
import sys

while True:
    inp = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if len(inp) == 0:
        break
    print ord(inp[0])
```

If I now call this via `ssh localhost python decode.py` and enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (i have to do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is interpreted as XON by my local shell and not passed on to the other side), then <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close the connection, i get `1`, `17` and `10` as ordinals, or `'\x01\x11\n'`, as expected.

I basically get the same by executing `printf '\x01\x11\n' | ssh localhost python decode.py`. If, however, I allocate a pty on the remote end via `printf '\x01\x11\n' | ssh -tt localhost python decode.py` the `\x11` is intercepted by the remote pty and not passed on through to the running script (i get `1`,`10` as output). In this case it helps to send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (`\x16`) before the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> that instructs the pty to pass the next character **V**erbatim.
As expected `printf '\x01\x16\x11\n' | ssh -tt localhost python decode.py` outputs `1`, `17` and `10`.

Comment: no avail on this one, ive added more detail if it helps

Comment: @AlexW I've updated my answer. Maybe this can point you in the right direction.

Comment: i just tried that and it returned this:Switch#
Switch#
*** baud: 9600
*** flow: none
*** parity: none
*** databits: 8
*** dtr: down

Switch# 
looks like thats another speical command?

Comment: @AlexW Looks like you've found you solution. Glad I could help.

Comment: Link is dead now

Answer (score 5):

Just as assumption: maybe pseudoterminal would help

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(...)
channel = сlient.get_transport().open_session()
channel.get_pty()
channel.settimeout(5)
channel.exec_command('\x11\x01')
```

Comment: this gives me " Non-ASCII character '\xd1' in file paramiko_test.py on line 20, but no encoding declared"